# pipenv FileNotFoundError when trying to create virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

I am trying to setup a virtual environment using pipenv with Python 3.8.5. I installed Miniconda3 and used pip install --user pipenv and it appeared to install fine. Running `pipenv --version` works fine.

```
Eamon@DESKTOP-J37G7TQ MINGW64 ~
$ pip install --user pipenv
Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in c:\users\eamon\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (2020.11.15)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\eamon\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pipenv) (20.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=18.0 in c:\users\eamon\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (20.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\eamon\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in c:\users\eamon\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (50.3.1.post20201107)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in c:\users\eamon\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from pipenv) (0.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in c:\users\eamon\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\eamon\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in c:\users\eamon\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in c:\users\eamon\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (3.0.12)
```

However, when trying to create a virtual environment with `pipenv --three`, the result is:

```
$ pipenv --three
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: C:\Users\Eamon\python_practice\pipenv-project1\Pipfile
Using C:/Users/Eamon/miniconda3/python.exe (3.8.5) to create virtualenv...
[   =] Creating virtual environment...FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\eamon\\miniconda3\\Lib\\venv\\scripts\\nt\\python.exe'

Failed creating virtual environment

[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:
Failed to create virtual environment.
```

I tried adding the path `'c:\\users\\eamon\\miniconda3\\Lib\\venv\\scripts\\nt\\python.exe'` to my environment variables path list but that didn't seem to work. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use pip package **virtualenv**. I've tried it on Ubuntu 20LTS and also Windows 10 and this works for me.

Install a python virtual environment builder:

```
python3 -m pip install virtualenv
```

Create a virtual environment named ***venv*** inside the project's directory: `virtualenv venv`

To activate this environment use this command inside project's directory: `source venv/bin/activate`

Install python modules dependencies listed in a requirements.txt:

```
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

*You should activate virtual environment when you working with python in this directory for package installation and for running commands in the project directory. When you need to deactivate the virtual environment do it using `deactivate` command.*

To deactivate environment simply run: `deactivate`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately after I installed virtualenv and tried to create venv with `virtualenv venv`, I again got a FileNotFoundError `c:\\users\\eamon\\miniconda3\\Lib\\venv\\scripts\\nt\\python.exe`

Comment: @EamonGibbons well it looks like it has something to do with `miniconda3` you've installed. What do you see if you open command prompt and type `python --version` or `python3 --version`. Also when I was playing around with python on Windows 10 I was also using Power Shell.

Comment: So when I run `python --version` I get 3.8.5, although when I run python3 --version it shows ```bash: /c/Users/Eamon/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3: Permission denied```. Is this where the problem is coming from?

Comment: @EamonGibbons this is what I see when in command prompt on my PC:

`C:\Windows\system32>python --version`
`Python 3.9.1`

`C:\Windows\system32>python3 --version`
`Python 3.9.1`

`C:\Windows\system32>where python`
`C:\Users\dubak\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`

`C:\Windows\system32>where python3`
`C:\Users\dubak\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe`

So I suggest as first thing to make sure both commands work on your PC, then maybe remove `miniconda3` first, setup `venv` and then instal `miniconda3` again.